# EF 6.1.3 takes more time (few minutes) but SSMS 17 executes in a second - SQL Server 2016 (AlwaysEncrypted) with encrypted columns

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6, .net-core, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

.NET Core REST API with EF 6.1.3 runs on net452 as targetFramework, **takes minutes** to execute a **Procedure** and return the results to model, but with same SP parameters it **takes only a second** to execute in SSMS 17. Its a SQL Server 2016 DB with few encrypted columns and have 30k+ records (DEV).

- Initially I was getting SQL timeout - now fixed by having
  **connection timeout** in the *appsettings.DEV.json*, also increased **command timeout** to infinite by having below on the constructor of the context:

  ```
  var adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)this;
  var objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;
  objectContext.CommandTimeout = 0 * 60;
  ```
- In SSMS 17, turned **OFF - SET ARITHABORT** to reproduce this slowness but could not reproduce - it executes in a second with/without ARITHABORT flag.
  SP does only SELECT (since it has AE columns, only equality conditions are performed on it)

Comment: what happens when you try adding option(recompile) hint in our client code

Comment: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: @TheGameiswar: It worked when SQL Server StoreProc having **WITH RECOMPILE** - now it takes only few seconds from EF. Thanks